# Kubernetes eviction APIs can't fully account for Elasticsearch cluster health?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I'm looking to perform an automatic rolling update of a Kubernetes cluster in a way that's ignorant of the details of the applications running on the cluster. In principle, PodDisruptionBudget should facilitate this.

Here's the snag: there's an Elasticsearch cluster running on this Kubernetes cluster, and I can't find a way to correctly express the "OK to evict an ES Pod" signal. Specifically, this seems to be a case where **the "this Pod can receive traffic" and "this Pod can be evicted" signals can't both be represented by `readinessProbe`.**

This ES cluster's indices have `number_of_replicas: 1`, and there's a PDB with `maxUnavailable: 1`. The ES Pods each specify a readiness probe that requests `/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow`.

As-is, if we evict an ES Pod, the replacement Pod will join the ES cluster, start up, and return to ready status while the ES cluster *as a whole* is still yellow and replicating shards (and thus it's still unsafe to evict any additional ES Pods).

Has anyone worked around this successfully? Am I misunderstanding the semantics of probes/PDBs?

---

Some options we've considered:

- Using `wait_for_status=green` in the readiness probe would mean that *all* ES Pods become unready when the ES cluster health is yellow.
- Increasing the ES indices' `number_of_replicas` to `2` only slightly reduces the probability of a rolling update damaging the ES cluster (assume these shards are slow to replicate).
- Ditto with setting a large `initialDelaySeconds` on the `readinessProbe`. It's possible for that to undershoot the time for shard replication to complete.
- Ditto with using a `preStop` hook ([this is the approach the community Helm chart appears to take](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/0a5ddac35d7e1a8820f3edb5198a648f706146ef/incubator/elasticsearch/templates/configmap.yaml#L122-L143)) and a long grace period.
- Decreasing the PDB's `maxUnavailable` to `0` means that the rolling update has to be run by a human who can remove the PDB, evaluate the status of the ES cluster, etc.
- A hypothetical, um, `evictablenessProbe` that checked `wait_for_status=green` would work, but no such API exists.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, by all means, saves yourself a ton of time and trouble and use the Helm chart:
https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/elasticsearch

But just in case you can't, or in case it helps others, I think what you're looking for is `/_cluster/health?local=true`, e.g:

```
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /_cluster/health?local=true
        port: 9200
```

Hope this helps!